# LogFile is not created

Tags: go

I am using Go.
I want to create a log file called webapp.log when I run go run main.go.
However, when I run go run main.go, the message `"2021/09/25 14:58:55 open : no such file or directory"` appears in the terminal and the log file is not created.
I can't tell from the message which location is causing the log file not to be created.
If anyone can help me, please let me know.
main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang_todo_app/config"
    "log"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Println(config.Config.Port)
  fmt.Println(config.Config.SQLDriver)
  fmt.Println(config.Config.DbName)
  fmt.Println(config.Config.LogFile)
  log.Println("test")
}
```

config/config.go

```
package config

import (
    "golang_todo_app/utils"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/go-ini/ini.v1"
)

type ConfigList struct {
    Port string
    SQLDriver string
    DbName string
    LogFile string
}

var Config ConfigList

func init () {
  LoadConfig()
  utils.LoggingSettings(Config.LogFile)
}

func LoadConfig() {
  cfg, err := ini.Load("config.ini")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln()
  }
  Config = ConfigList{
    Port: cfg.Section("web").Key("port").MustString("8080"),
    SQLDriver: cfg.Section("db").Key("driver").String(),
    DbName: cfg.Section("db").Key("name").String(),
    LogFile: cfg.Section("web").Key("logfile").String(),
  }
}
```

utils/logging.go

```
package utils

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func LoggingSettings(logFile string) {
  logfile, err := os.OpenFile(logFile, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
  }
  multiLogFile := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logfile)
  log.SetFlags(log.Ldate | log.Ltime | log.Lshortfile)
  log.SetOutput(multiLogFile)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "2021/09/25 14:58:55 open : no such file or directory"

Have a look of your code, the most possible place which will raise this error is next:

```
logfile, err := os.OpenFile(logFile, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
```

Usually if we open a file with no permission e.g. /root/log.txt, it could produce next:

```
2021/09/25 17:50:07 open /root/log.txt: permission denied
```

You could see the `/root/log.txt` will be displayed to tell user which file can't be open, but for you, your error return nothing after `open`. This means for next code:

```
LoggingSettings(Config.LogFile)
```

The `Config.LogFile` parser returns nothing. The correct `ini` setting maybe next:

**config.ini:**

```
[web]
logfile=/tmp/log.txt
```

You should check your `ini` file to see if any mistake makes the code can't parse a valid `logfile` value.

**BTW**, next code will happen when you import `"golang_todo_app/config"`, so your print in `main` function executed after next function, your print in main won't have chance to run if the error haapens in `init`.

```
func init () {
  LoadConfig()
  utils.LoggingSettings(Config.LogFile)
}
```